# Assign html attribute to php variable using inline javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the id attribute of a html link as a php variable.  I am trying to do this using javascript as below:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileModal" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="<?php $profile_id='<script> function(){ var pid = $(this).attr(\"id\")}; document.write(pid);  }<\/script>';?>"><?php echo $first_name; ?></a>
```

I can document.write static text out of that function but there is no output when I add:

```
var id = $(this).attr(\"id\");
```

and try output that.

The links are on the first name in a table that will open a modal. How can I make this happen?

Comment: why are u include `script` tag in onclick

Comment: @susheel Because its wrapped in the <?php ?> tags at the $profile_id variable assignment

Comment: what you are doing it's an JQUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inline event handlers, don't use `<script>` tags.

```
onclick="var pid = $(this).attr(\"id\")}; document.write(pid);"
```

Note `document.write()` overwrites the whole page content.

Unless you're just calling a function, inline handlers get ugly, as your code shows, so consider using unobtrusive JavaScript to assign the event handlers.

For example if you give the links a class:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myClass').click(function(){
        console.log( this.id );
    });
});
```